# Typescript Return the enum values in parameter using a generic enum type method

Tags: typescript, enums, optional-parameters, function-definition, generic-type-parameters

I need to return a list with all values of an Enum (specified as parameter or generic). If the user has a specific role I need only some of the Enum values given as parameter.

I considered to write the two parameters as a tuple because they are either given both or none.
My first try would look like this:

```
getItemsBasedOnRole<T extends enum>(...[role, items]?: [UserRole, T[]]) : string[]
{
    const allValues = Object.values(T);
    if (role && items) // tuple parameter exists
        if (this.securityService.getUser.role === role)
            return items;

    return allValues;
}

const result = getItemsBasedOnRole<MyEnum>([ClientRole], [MyEnum.Value1, MyEnum.Value3]);
// returns [MyEnum.Value1, MyEnum.Value3]

const result = getItemsBasedOnRole<MyEnum>();
// returns [MyEnum.Value1, MyEnum.Value2, MyEnum.Value3]


export enum MyEnum{
    Value1 = 'Value1',
    Value2 = 'Value2',
    Value3 = 'Value3',
}
```

The problems are in Typescript:

- `T extends enum` does not exist.
  Solution: Replaced with `T extends { [s: number]: string }`
- `Object.values(T)` needs a value and T is a type.
  Considered adding a parameter `enumValue: T` but calling the method I could not pass `MyEnum`, it was requiring `MyEnum.ValueX`.
  No solution found for this.
- `[role, items]?` optional tuple does not exist.
  No solution found for this.

My last attempt, which shows the errors in the above list:

```
getItemsBasedOnRole<T extends { [s: number]: string }>(enumValue: T, ...[role, items]: [UserRole, T[]]): string[]
```

The above problems are related to types and function definition and I just want to return a dynamic list. I am open to any ideas: multiple functions, using parameter instead of generic type, etc.

Comment: Please, make sure that the code doesn't contain pseudocode

Comment: Does [this approach](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgJQPYBtoF4p2IgSwDsBzAbgFgAoagEwgGN0BDRaAMwFciHgDUiUEhGABJYBAC2cAELMEtAPJE0mADwAVKBAAeEorThRkjVIlpq8hUgBpc+YiQB8TgBSoARgCsAXFA12AHTBrCRwfgDaiBgQAPx+8EiqEHYAbszonBBw8f4RANYQIKjs-gC6EWVlAJR+Vo6V1NS6YGbAUAwCeFAAsiAAokScklA4AN7UUFAAahlZAIx+AOSzmRDzSzaTM3MQAEzLq1l7m9tHEADMh7sXp1QAvlDyHV3tcMx8cOwE2cam5pYHLZ7NZnE0qMIxBJpHIFMpkq4+oNhnYltFMJsoBEVrsNqjzicakA) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing? I don't think that it is feasible with enums

Comment: Yes! Following that, [my code works](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JABwTglgbghgLgUwAQHMFwKIDsCuBbANRgBscEBnAIQE8AlAe2IQB4AVJBAD0SwBNykAbyQBtcgC4kuPACMEYALqTycSFhRIAvgD4AFAmlFSCSawA0SAHTWYYFBNFhGFAPySAquXkMm5EQosIRDxyNyRWEQBrBGp6ADNwhX8FAEplVQh1fyEAWAAoYGAIBN1bexEABgUkADIapDK-AEZU3ILCgGN6LBUkAAsYcgBBDo6KcgBuJAB6aatLAGF6PBAcRF4kHHJMjRgsejg++SQvMCgIMfzCopKB4dHxlLbr4DB0HDAsBrtm6sGTjJZBQTK6FTSg8HtN5wD5fADyMgAVggOnBLLBjOR9IYSGQUiCCpogA). That part helped me "T[keyof T][]". If you know how to refer 'items' instead of args[1] to be more clear then that would perfect my method.

Comment: I managed to use an enum without creating Record class. And I have multiple roles given as parameter, thats just an adaptation for my code.

Comment: `If you know how to refer 'items' instead of args[1] to be more clear then that would perfect my method`. Can you elaborate? I'm not sure if I understood you

Comment: just to call it `items` instead of `values`?

Comment: in my method i use the parameters like this
'if (args[0] && args[1])' and it would be better like this 'if (roles && items)' the tuple parameter actual names.

Comment: Doesn't destructing like in [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgJQPYBtoF4p2IgSwDsBzAbgFgAoagMwFciBjYA1IqEiYASWAgC2cAEIBDBABMA8kTSYAPABUoEAB78iEuFGQQmqRBPl5CpADS58xEgD4bAClQAjAFYAuKIosA6X6MQkcB4A2ogYEAD8HvBIchAWBPxCUZ7BANYQIKi0ngC6wbm5AJQeJtYFUADe1FBQ+kR4UKHhCUlwuVA4-oGUNFS1iNz0iBwFvQC+1NRqYAbAdeyNALIgAKJE9AKdVTVQAGqi6PQQAIweAOQHR6fnZrtXxwBMFw8Qj7f3h8cAzC9fEN8PlRxlBxAsGvM4KJWHBaAQINpdPpDMYrOZLKZbFMqFxeG0xJIZHF7Ct1psLOcwphbk1Lv8TjS6dd3sUgA) work for you?

Comment: Yes, thats the last missing piece! You can write an answer.

Comment: okay, will do when I get a chance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using constant objects instead of `enums`, since they are more predictable and easier to manipulate. We will need to apply [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) to prevent the compiler from widening the type of the object and to make sure that the object is type-safe, we are going to use [satisfies](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html) operator:

```
export const MyEnum = {
  Value1: 'Value1',
  Value2: 'Value2',
  Value3: 'Value3',
} as const satisfies Record<string, string>
```

Since, our enum is `Record<string, string>` we will change the constraint of the generic argument to the relevant one:

```
declare function getItemsBasedOnRole<T extends Record<string, string>>(obj: T, ...args:[something]) {}
```

To get the values of the whole object, we are going to use [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html):
`T[keyof T]` will give the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#union-types) of all values:

```
declare function getItemsBasedOnRole<T extends Record<string, string>>(obj: T, ...args: [role?: UserRole, values?: T[keyof T][]]): string[]
```

Usage:

```
getItemsBasedOnRole(MyEnum, 'role', ['Value1', 'Value2'])
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgJQPYBtoF4p2IgSwDsBzAbgFgAoagEwgGN0BDRaAMwFciHgDUiUEhGABJYBAC2cAELMEtAPJE0mADwAVKBAAeEorThRkjVIlpq8hUgBpc+YiQB8TgBSoARgCsAXFA12AHTBrCRwfgDaiBgQAPx+8EiqEHYAbszonBBw8f4RANYQIKjs-gC6EWVlAJR+Vo6V1NS6YGbAUAwCeFAAsiAAokScklA4AN7UUFAAahlZAIx+AOSzmRDzSzaTM3MQAEzLq1l7m9tHEADMh7sXp1QAvlDyHV3tcMx8cOwE2cam5pYHLZ7NZnE0qMIxBJpHIFMpkq4+oNhnYltFMJsoBEVrsNqjzicakA)